# Unable to throw exception by KafkaTemplate when topic is not available/ kafka broker is down

Tags: spring-kafka

I am sending message to Kafka by Kafka Template but I wanted to test exception, So I have provided wrong topic name but When I run the code, it says " Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {ocf-oots-gr-outbound_123=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE" not available but the topic itself is created in Kafka that I can also see through Kafka tool and when broker is stopped, it is also not throwing exception.

### Code:

```
KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate = (KafkaTemplate<String, Object>) CommonAppContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("kafkaTemplate");
                    //kafkaTemplate.send(CommonAppContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment().getProperty("kafka.transalators.outbound.topic"), kafkaMessageFormat);

ListenableFuture listenableFuture = kafkaTemplate.send(CommonAppContextProvider.getApplicationContext().
                    getEnvironment().getProperty("kafka.transalators.outbound.topic"), kafkaMessageFormat);

listenableFuture.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<?, ?>>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(SendResult<?, ?> result) {
                            System.out.println("Sent");

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                            throw new KafkaException();
                        }

                    });
                }
```

It should throw exception may be KafkaException, TimeOutException, Interrupted exception etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `get(time, timeUnit)` on the future to get the result (success or otherwise).

Comment: Got the solution by calling get().

Comment: but this will going to wait until you get the response from it, which makes it sync call, can we make it async instead.

Comment: See the `listenableFuture.addCallback` in the question - the exception is provided asynchronously there.